# python requests import error

Tags: python, request, attributeerror

When I try to import the `requests` module:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gek0n\Desktop\requests.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\gek0n\Desktop\requests.py", line 3, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Than I checked Stack Overflow and found this:

```
print dir(requests)
```

And instead of this:

```
['ConnectionError', 'HTTPError', 'Request', 'RequestException', 'Response', 'Session', 'Timeout', 'TooManyRedirects', 'URLRequired', '__author__', '__build__', '__builtins__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__title__', '__version__', '_oauth', 'api', 'auth', 'certs', 'codes', 'compat', 'cookies', 'defaults', 'delete', 'exceptions', 'get', 'head', 'hooks', 'models', 'options', 'packages', 'patch', 'post', 'put', 'request', 'safe_mode', 'session', 'sessions', 'status_codes', 'structures', 'utils']
```

I had this:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'requests']
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'requests']
```

Yes! There are two strings and only six elements. Why is that? What's wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you create your own file called `requests.py`?  Judging from the path it looks like you did.  Name your file something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You named your script `requests.py` and it is being imported instead of the library.

Because your `import requests` line is the first in the module, that is also the only object (apart from the standard double-underscore values) found in your module at the time it imports itself again, which is why you see `'requests'` listed in the `dir()` output.

Rename your script.